# Min of StringTokenizer is error?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have code to proceed and get min of `StringTokenizer` but the result is `min = 999999`.

```
public static double minStringTokenizer(StringTokenizer stz) {
    double min = 999999;
    while (stz.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String temp1 = stz.nextToken();
        double temp2 = Double.parseDouble(temp1);
        if (min > temp2) {
            min = temp2;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: What's your input? Maybe it is empty.

Comment: Or every value is greater than 999999?

Comment: my input is stz=new Stringtokenizer("111 333 42 43"," "); but result always 999999

Comment: Then I can't reproduce. Your code given as input `new StringTokenizer("111 333 42 43"," ")` outputs the expected `42.0`.

Comment: Did you use the same StringTokenizer before, perhaps for finding the maximum? You need to recreate it for another pass!

Comment: thanks @laune. I know you're wrong place before

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Like your thing say :D

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(minStringTokenizer(new StringTokenizer("1,2,99,-3,4,888,-1",",")));
        System.out.println(minStringTokenizer(new StringTokenizer("1199999999999,99999999999",",")));
        System.out.println(minStringTokenizer(new StringTokenizer("5,4,3,2",",")));

        //throws err
        //System.out.println(minStringTokenizer(new StringTokenizer("5xxx,4,3,2",",")));
    }

    public static double minStringTokenizer(StringTokenizer stz) {

        if(stz==null || !stz.hasMoreTokens()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("stz may not be null or empty");
        }

        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        while (stz.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String temp1 = stz.nextToken();
            double temp2 = Double.parseDouble(temp1);
            min = Math.min(min, temp2);
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```